# How can I handle ImmutableMultiDict with FastAPI

Tags: fastapi

I am using FastApi and I am trying to handle /commands from Slack. Slack send a HTTP POST method with this data type as a body: ImmutableMultiDict.
I am having this error message: ERROR CODE 422 unprocessable entity.

I wanted to know if any of you guys know how can I handle this data types. Because I am not sure if FastApi can handle it.

Comment: Add samples. How your request body looks, what is the expected output etc.

Comment: This is the payload of the request that Slack is sending:

`ImmutableMultiDict([('token', 'ROrCSlp6ZZa5B9NYXHz8BPmQ'), ('team_id', ''), ('team_domain', ''), ('channel_id', '), ('channel_name', 'directmessage'), ('user_id', ''), ('user_name', ''), ('command', '/help'), ('text', 'hola matias'), ('api_app_id', ''), ('response_url', 'https://hooks.slack.com/commands/T0TQY6K/1469497887508/0x9swqeFKgDB4WJVL15E4'), ('trigger_id', '1475965553.2435848223.fab62de3ebbc231cf21db665def03b90')])`

I never see before this kind of data type.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing some research and I could find a solution.
I used the method body from Request

@app.post("/api/help")

async def helper(req: Request):

body     = await req.body()